# Live Migration of Repository Root

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Our VisualSVN server (SE) currently stores its repositories in "C:\Repositories" but given the growth of our repositories the C: drive is starting to fill up. We would like to move the entire repository root to the second drive in the server (D:) which has plenty of space for the foreseeable future.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107620/how-to-change-where-subversion-repositories-are-stored) which tells me how to change the root, but as that question concerned a fresh install the preservation of existing data wasn't a concern. After some research I've found that there are several ways of preserving the existing repositories:

- straight-up file copy in explorer: should preserve all data but I'm hesitant to trust Windows with this task
- `svnadmin dump` to a dumpfile, then load the dumpfile at the new location
- `svnadmin hotcopy` the repositories to the new location

I'd like to have your input on which approach would be preferable. I'd prefer the hotcopy method if it's robust enough as dumping all repositories would take quite a while. The dump method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516140/upgrading-subversion-server-from-1-5-5-to-1-6-5-dump-upgrade-reload-exact-ste) but seems to include steps that are unnecessary for my situation as I'm keeping everything on the same server.

Additionally, I'd like to ask how we would best proceed with this migration to keep downtime to a minimum. I'd like to prevent users from committing changes while the files are being copied. Can I just shut the SVN service down while I'm changing the root and copying the files?

Finally, I'd like to use this opportunity to upgrade the server from 2.5.2 to 2.5.8. Should I do this after the file copy? Should I first restart the service and then shut it down again so it processes and checks the moved repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `svnadmin hotcopy` for each repository or `xcopy /E /H C:\Repositories D:\Repositories`. Don't forget to copy authorization files (authz, authz-windows and htpasswd). You have to stop VisualSVN Server before migration.

`svnadmin dump` is not required and as you mentioned really time consuming process.

It better to upgrade VisualSVN Server after repositories migration and required reconfiguration. In some upgrades VisualSVN Server needs access to repositories folder for upgrading.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the cleanest and most complete answer for my situation. The other answers suggest some valid alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

These are some steps you can use. The use of this python script will make your task easier and benefit you in the future for taking daily backups of your repository.

1. On VisualSVNServer, go to properties and change the Repositories Root to your new location. Assuming "D:\Repositories".
2. Download Python 2.7 (if you don't already have it installed).
3. Download "hot-backup.py"
4. Execute the following from a command window.

   ```
   hot-backup.py C:\Repositories\<YourRepoName>  D:\Repositories\<YourRepoName>
   ```
5. Upgrade your SVN Version

This should do the trick. Good luck  !!!

Answer (score 1):

- Xcopy SVN-Parent to new location
- Edit (by hand) httpd.conf of VisualSVN Server, `SVNParentPath` parameter
- Restart VisualSVN Server from it's MMC-applet